# right-click (xdg-open) opened up some opaque windows covering my screen; xkill won't kill them

Tags: xorg, ubuntu-12.04, window-manager, xdg, compositing

I right-clicked on something in chromium with relatively low memory. Chromium opened up some opaque right-click boxes and never filled them in and won't kill them. These are now covering part of all of my virtual desktops. (not virtual console though)

[image: window covered by bizarre right-click xdg-open boxes]

I got information on them with `xprop` and `xwininfo`. Here's an example from each:

```
$ xprop
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
        window id # of group leader: 0x7600001
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 125152843
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 3142781307
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x775aca9
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x7600001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 23912
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "scheherezade"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified location: 0, 0
        program specified minimum size: 247 by 140
        program specified maximum size: 247 by 140
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "chromium-browser", "Chromium-browser"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "Chromium"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Chromium"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Chromium"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Chromium"
```

and

```
$ xwininfo

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x775ac2d "Chromium"

  Absolute upper-left X:  591
  Absolute upper-left Y:  614
  Relative upper-left X:  591
  Relative upper-left Y:  614
  Width: 247
  Height: 140
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x21
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x20 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: yes
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: yes
  Corners:  +591+614  -562+614  -562-296  +591-296
  -geometry 247x140+591+614
```

`xkill` doesn't clear the zombie dialogs away. Neither does `killall xdg-open`. There are some defunct Chromium processes in `ps -u $USER -o comm`. Someone suggested killing `X` but I want to keep all my tabs open.

This is Ubuntu 12.04, Awesome Window Manager, no compositing.

Comment: did you try 'kill -9 xdg-open'?

Comment: @mcalex I did, unfortunately that didn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually quit `chromium` and the problem went away.